# Why does my loop prints error while searching for opertators when they are in the argument?

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to solve the Arithmethic Formater from FCC. One of the conditions is:

> The operator must be '+' or '-'.

I isolated the part where the codes check if one of this conditions are true.
When the operator are '+' or '-' the code outputs an error. Why does this happen?
The loop is inside a function which gives a list of problems to solve.

```
for problem in problems:
    splitted_problem = problem.split()
    operator = splitted_problem[1]
    if operator != '+' or operator != '-' :
        return print("Error: Operator must be '+' or '-'.")
```

Comment: should be `and` and not `or`. Because ANY char will be either different of + or different of -

Comment: What do you think *return print...* is going to do? Also, you could consider writing: *if operator not in '+-'*

Comment: Note though that `if operator not in '+-'` will accept '+-' as a valid operator, which is probably not intended. Rather use `if operator not in ['+', '-']` to avoid that

Answer (score 0):

As explained by others in the comments of your post:

1. It should be `and` and not `or`. This code will not accept `-` because the first "not plus" condition would be fulfilled. Similarly `+` fulfills the "not minus" condition.
2. Unless this code is in a function, you cannot use the return statement. `print()` should be sufficient. [return statements](https://realpython.com/python-return-statement/)

```py
for problem in problems:
    splitted_problem = problem.split()
    operator = splitted_problem[1]
    if operator != '+' and operator != '-':
        print("Error: Operator must be '+' or '-'.")
```